# Ускорение неполного запроса

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть база в которую потоком идут данные с инфой о машинах, что попадают на камеры.
Необходимо реализовать возможность быстрого поиска по полю с данными гос.номера автомобиля, если имеется часть номера.
LIKE запрос работает очень медленно, учитывая многомиллионную базу.
Думаю насчет утилиты pg_trgm, но она требует индексации, что проблематично при большом потоке данных.
Что скажете, Уважаемые коллеги?

Comment: В чём проблематичность индекса? У вас поток в сотни тысяч insert в секунду и "многомиллионная база" - это за минуту работы?

Comment: *LIKE запрос работает очень медленно* LIKE не по префиксу вообще тормоз. Ибо фуллскан. *возможность быстрого поиска* Быстрого - это насколько? *учитывая многомиллионную базу* Много - это сколько? *при большом потоке данных* Это сколько инсертов и селектов в секунду?

Comment: А какая часть номера имеется - всегда одна и та же или разные? Тут можно много вариантов придумать.